# RoR's flash feature isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In the signin form as users clicks the signin button to signin, the signin form calls the create action via the sessions resource.

Here is the action:

```
 def create
   user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
   if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     #Sign the user in and redirect to user's main page
   else
    flash[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
    render 'new'
  end
 end
```

Although the flash[:error] isn't working.

I tried placing a 'flash[:notice]' in the static pages controller to flash a notice whenever the home page is redirected to, although that doesn't work either.

My test suit gives me this error

```
Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }
   expected css "div.alert.alert-error" with text "Invalid" to return something
```

Is this a problem with my css?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you add code to display the flash in your layout or view template?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I hadn't included that in application.html.erb

Comment: Chris, would you mind copy and pasting what you wrote as an answer so I can give you credit for it?

Comment: Added it as an answer with some code for anyone who happens on this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add code to display the flash in your layout or view template?

It looks like maybe you're using Bootstrap, so you could do something similar to this in your layout file (`views/layouts/application.html.erb` or other layout):

```
<% flash.each do |key, message| %>
  <div id="flash-<%= key %>" class="alert alert-<%= key %> fade in">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to use flash.now[:error], since you're rendering the view aftewards.

```
flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash/now

Comment: thanks for your help. It turns out the issue was that I hadn't included code to actually input the error messages into the view templates.